# How to set conditional properties on style in WindowGroup?

Tags: swift, swiftui, visionos, swiftui-windowgroup

I'm working on a visionOS app which relies heavily on window groups. If you use window style plain, you can remove the glass background which I would like to do sometimes. Other times I would like the glass. The property window style is apparently a protocol and I can't use a ternary operator when trying to set these as it requires the enum type to be the same. How can I go about this?

I gave the code down below showing that if I use each one separately it works fine but if I try to tie it to a boolean it errors. I've included the error message next to each attempt.

```swift
WindowGroup {
    //Display the tutorial view.
    SetupView()
}
//This Works
.windowStyle(.plain)

//This also works
.windowStyle(.automatic)

//But they can't combine. What I have tried.
.windowStyle(showGlassBackground ? .plain : .automatic) //Member 'automatic' in 'PlainWindowStyle' produces result of type 'DefaultWindowStyle', but context expects 'PlainWindowStyle'
.windowStyle(showGlassBackground ? (.plain as WindowStyle) : (.automatic as WindowStyle) //Type 'any WindowStyle' cannot conform to 'WindowStyle'
.windowStyle(showGlassBackground ? (PlainWindowStyle.plain as any WindowStyle) : (DefaultWindowStyle.automatic as any WindowStyle)) //Value of type 'any WindowStyle' has no member 'windowStyle'
.windowStyle(showGlassBackground ? (PlainWindowStyle.plain as WindowStyle) : (DefaultWindowStyle.automatic as WindowStyle)) //Type 'any WindowStyle' cannot conform to 'WindowStyle'
.windowStyle(showGlassBackground ? WindowStyle(.plain) : WindowStyle(.automatic)) // 'any WindowStyle' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
```

Comment: Have a look at the declaration of [`WindowGroup.windowStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scene/windowstyle(_:)). It's generic over `S: WindowStyle`, and returns a `some Scene`. Mostly likely, the concrete type returned under that `some Scene` depends on the type of `S`, so you can't just have two different possible styles passed in, because the output type wouldn't work. I'm not sure how to work around this, though.

Comment: I tried solving with extensions on Scene and other trickeries but, I think Apple has really messed up this one!

Comment: @MatBuompy Not really, we're just having a skill issue haha. I think you just need to have something of the form `if showGlassBackground { ...windowStyle(.plain) } else {  ...windowStyle(.automatic) }`. I.e., you'll need two different calls to `windowStyle`, because you're calling them with two different generic arguments.

Comment: I think I tried that too. If you managed to accomplish that post it as an answer please, I'm curious 

Comment: @MatBuompy I don't have the iOS sdk installed right now, so I can't really play around with this. I can give some tips though! I think when you do that, the issue you get is that the two branches of the `if` statement have two different types of results. When you use `.windowStyle(.automatic)`, the resulting type (checked with `print(type(of: ...))` is something like `ModifiedContent<WindowGroup<ContentView>, WindowStyleModifier<DefaultWindowStyle>>`, which is the underlying type being hidden behind the `some Scene` facade. When you use `.plain`, it'll be a different incompatible type instead.

Comment: @MatBuompy When you have this problem with Views, the solution is to use an [`AnyView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/anyview) to erase the concrete type away, and make both branches of an `if` return the same type (`AnyView`). Unfortunately, I don't see anything like an `AnyScene` in the SwiftUI docs. I wonder if switching to `-> any Scene` instead would work. (`AnyView` was added to SwiftUI before generalized existentials existed in Swift, i.e. before it was possible to write `any View`).

Comment: @Alexander The compiler did suggest me to use any Scene, in fact. But it is not good practice to use AnyView, and I think the same goes for Scene.

Comment: @MatBuompy It's not good practice when there's an alternative, but I don't think there is an alternative here. It's bad practice because it removes static type information (which could otherwise be used for better inlining/optimization), but that's pretty much exactly what this situation calls for

Comment: I know, and I totally agree @Alexander.

Comment: Well? did it work?

Comment: @Alexander While I didn't get it to work with window style, I did get it to work another way and included that in my answer below.

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 Nicely done. I played around with it some more, and I got nothing. You can't wrap this in a function returning `any Scene`. The function will compile, but you can't use it from within the view builder. You also can't wrap the whole thing in a `if`/`else` or conditional operator, because [`SceneBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scenebuilder) doesn't have `buildConditional` ("Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'SceneBuilder'")

Answer (score 1):

So I would still love to hear how this could be done, as like @Alexander said this is most likely a skill issue, but I found a way to get this to work the way I wanted. If you set the window style to plain, the glass window disappears but then you can put in glass effect separately. That can be ? into an always and never case that works for what I need.

```
WindowGroup {
    SetupView().glassBackgroundEffect(displayMode: showGlassBackground ? .always : .never)
}.windowStyle(.plain)
```

Comment: If you still want other answers then it's probably best not to accept your own answer. People will see the checkmark and assume there's no need for more answers.

Comment: Good point, I removed it.